# Foreach add wpdb->insert adding unexpected number of rows

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to insert a row foreach value found in an array into the wordpress database. However, when saving the new post i'm getting an unexpected number of rows in the table?

For example, if i set the maximum entries to 4 and click save i end up with 6 rows?

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'mp_sync_on_product_save', 10, 1 );
function mp_sync_on_product_save( $product_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $qty = get_field('maximum_entries', $product_id);
    print_r($qty);
    $array = range(1, $qty);

    foreach ($array as $ticket) {
     $wpdb->insert('wp_tickets', array(
        'ticket_number' => $ticket,
     ));
    }
}
```

Var dump of $array

```
array (size=4)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 4
```

Var dump of $qty

```
string '4'
```

Output of inserted rows into wp_tickets

```
id--order_id--ticket_number--lottery_id 
44----0----------1----------------0
45----0----------0----------------0
46----0----------1----------------0
47----0----------2----------------0
48----0----------3----------------0
49----0----------4----------------0
```

Updated code

```
add_action('save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 100, 3);
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

        global $wpdb;
        global $post;

        if( ! ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id) || wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) ) ) {

        $qty = wc_clean( $_POST['_max_tickets']);
    $array = range(1, $qty);

    foreach ($array as $ticket) {
     $wpdb->insert('wp_tickets', array(
         'ticket_number' => $ticket,
         'lottery_id' => $post_id,
     ));
    }

        }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the `var_dump()` (or equivalent) of `$qty` that is causing this discrepancy between your expectation and reality?

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: You still did not provide the `var_dump()` of `$qty`.

Comment: Apologies, i've included that now

Comment: Is it also possible for you to provide what's been inserted into the SQL table as a result of this operation running once?

Comment: Sure, i've added that now. Apologies for the formatting

Comment: If that's exactly your code and your output, then something is definitely off. Could it be that when you have another action firing on save_post that is inserting into the db?

Comment: Im using Wordpress so the post is being saved into another table but I don't have any other code which would be saving into the wp_tickets table

Comment: Okay, so when i manually add numbers into $array such as array(1,2,3,4,5) it works. So i believe it's something to do with the get_field. Is it because I'm calling get_field whilst the the post is being saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because as per wordpress core functionality save_post hook triggering multiple times(eg: autosave) see the doc [Here](https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-save_post-called-twice/)

So first time $qty gets null.So $array value will be

> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(0) }

You need to rewrite code as follows.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'mp_sync_on_product_save', 11, 1 );
function mp_sync_on_product_save( $product_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if( ! ( wp_is_post_revision( $product_id) || wp_is_post_autosave( $product_id ) ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        $qty = get_field('maximum_entries', $product_id);

        $array = range(1, $qty);

        foreach ($array as $ticket) {
         $wpdb->insert('wp_tickets', array(
            'ticket_number' => $ticket,
         ));
        }
    }
}
```

> NB : keep add_action priority more than 10 because its default
>   priority

Comment: Hi @Mohammed,i've added what you've suggested but it's still not working

Comment: is it inserting 6 rows again?

Comment: Yes it was, i changed the priority to 10, 3 instead and it's looks like it's working now

Comment: fourth one is accepted arguments, not priority https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Comment: Hi, i've changed this to 11, 3 and it's still adding two rows to the top